# Unable to link to "dinput.lib" even after changing to DirectX 8 API

Tags: directx

I'm trying to build the [Gens](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gens/) emulator from its source on SourceForge. I've got Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 on my machine. I ran into the error `fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'dinput.lib'` After installing the DirectX SDK, I kept getting the error. I found a suggestion to change from "DirectInputCreate" to "DirectInput8Create" and made all the associated changes, but it's still attempting to reference "dinput.lib" instead of "dinput8.lib". Is there something obvious I'm missing?

Comment: I am currently getting the same problem. However, if I change my build from Debug to Release then it builds. Obviously not a complete solution but I'm hoping it leads to one.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. You can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174).